# access another class object through import

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a program name "new.py" with":

```
class hello:

    def __init__(self, summary):
        self.summary = summary


    def hi(self):
        print self.summary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = hello(summary = "this is a hello program")
    h.hi()
```

when i want to access the function hi into the another program name another.py, then i am not able to access the function.. please help me and correct me also...
another.py:

```
import new 

    class another:

        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value

        def show(self):
            print "value is %s" % self.value
            new.hi()
            print "done"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = another(value = "this is a another value")
        a.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
new.hi()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute hi
```

Comment: You need to somewhere define an instance of `hello` in `another.py`. `new.hi` is not defined, but `new.hello`.

Comment: Sorry but still showing error:  global name "new" is not defined"...I tried with from new import hello

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not initializing the hello object. So you need to do this somewhere before you call the hi function:

```
        n  = new.hello('some string')
```

then you can call:

```
       n.hi()
```

Comment: with out initialing the hello object we can not do with the "import" module_name..

Comment: Sorry i don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is you do:

```
import new
```

and then:

```
new.hi()
```

hi() is not defined in new, it's defined in new.hello, which is your class.
You need to create a new instance of the class hello and call hi() from there.